# Unit testing Command Line Tool target in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest

I’ve been struggling for hours trying to find a way to unit test my code. There’s no way to select the main target (`MazeGeneratorTests` is there b/c I already created it).

[image: Screenshot of test target creation dialog]

Here’s what the Project Navigator looks like (don’t mind the random structure):

[image: Project Navigator]

After importing with `@testable import MazeGenerator`, calling anything from the module causes an `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` error, e.g.:

```swift
func testPerformanceExample() throws {
    measure {
        let _ = generateNodes(rows: 20, cols: 20)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your project on github?

Comment: Sure, here it is: [Link](https://github.com/Imericxu/MazeGenerator-Swift).

Comment: @TpoM6oH Let me know if there’s something else I need to commit, idrk what files are needed.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** I’ve realized that the better way to achieve this is by using a static library (see [Library vs. Framework](https://medium.com/@m.tabrizi/ios-library-vs-framework-30866c41f100). Here’s an example repo showing how to achieve this: [Imericxu/example-testable-swift-cli](https://github.com/Imericxu/example-testable-swift-cli).

I figured it out. The “Command Line Tool” target is kind of finicky, so you need to separate all your logic into a new Framework target—this comes with a unit test target—and make everything you want to be visible `public`. Then build and import the framework into your `main.swift` file.

Comment: Hi,  could you elaborate more on how did you solve this? the repo is not found. Thanks!

Comment: @Vina I’ve updated my answer!

Comment: It might be better to add some details about how to do the static library approach, instead of just a link to the repo. The link is fine but things can change. Let's try to keep this answer useful even if, say, the example repo were to vanish from the network.

Comment: @matt , the link that he put in the answer is now good :)